# How to reduce formula size. Error : Compiled formula is too big to execute

Tags: formula-field

I am getting error when i added new status to my application. the error is

`Formula(s) that reference this field are no longer valid: Compiled formula is too big to execute (5235 characters). Maximum size is 5000 characters".`

Formula which returns Number:

```
CASE(TEXT(Status__c), 
'Quantity Placed', 1, 
'Quantity Need to be Arrange', 2, 
'Quantity Need to be ReArrange', 3, 
'Quantity Cancelled', 4, 
'Quantity Completed', 5, 
'Quantity INPROCESS', 6, 
'Quantity Closed', 7, 
'Quantity Not Reached', 8, 
'Quantity Opened', 9, 
'Quantity ReOpened', 10, 
'Quantity Changed', 11, 
'Quantity Need to be review/change',12,
'Quantity Awaiting payment', 13, 
'Quantity pending', 14, 
'Quantity Need to be approve',15,0)
```

How can i reduce this formula size and where can i see the formula size and Compiled formula.?

Please help

Comment: Is `Status__c` a formula field by itself? It looks to be, looking at the amount of characters in this formula. Could you post the `Status__c` field formula as well?

Comment: @RobinDeBondt Thanks for the response.Status__c is PickList not formula field and contains all the values like Quantity Placed,Quantity Need to be Arrange....

Comment: Very strange that you are hitting the limit with such a simple formula in that case. I've experienced the same issue before, but in those cases, it was almost always by referencing another formula field.

Comment: I don't think you need to use text with a picklist while using case.  Not sure if that is the problem though.

Comment: @Girbot i checked,problem not with Text.

Comment: @NullReferenceException Have you checked whether a formula in a different field is referencing this formula field? The error message sounds consistent with that, so that when you add the new status in this small formula, the other formula is pushed over the limit. If you are lucky you may be able to restructure the other formula to reference this field less and so stay within the size limit.

Comment: @KeithC Yes I am using this formula field in another formula field.Usage is :CASE(TEXT(Status_Id__c),
'1','Placed',
'2','Awaiting',
'3','Awaiting',
'9','Awaiting',
'10','Awaiting',
'15','Awaiting','Awaiting payment')

Comment: @NullReferenceException That doesn't look like it would cause a problem. I suggest you review the object field definitions to see if there is yet another field that uses this value.

Comment: @KeithC No i am not using it any other field, but does it affect if this field used in Controller and Reports..The formula field declared in my previous comment,i used in many reports...

Comment: @NullReferenceException I would have guessed no but may be wrong; is any report name mentioned anywhere in the errors?

Comment: @KeithC Thank you for your response.No errors found till now in the report.but i didnt understand 'is any report name mentioned anywhere in the errors?' means.

Comment: @NullReferenceException I was asking if any of the error messages about formula length mentioned reports.

Comment: @KeithC i didnt get any error messages about formula length..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16703/discussion-between-nullreferenceexception-and-keith-c).